# update collection1 with values from collection2

Tags: php, laravel

First, let me apoligise for the picture. I know its not suppose to be posted like this.

Bellow I have two collections. I want to update the key->value pair in `collection1` with the values in `collection2`. `Collection1` contains way more items including the ones in `collection2`

The keys in `collection2` exist 100% in `collection1`.

I have tried a few suggestions without success like

```
$updatedCollection = $collection1->map(function ($item) use ($collection2) {
    $matchingItem = $collection2->where('id', $item['id'])->first();
    
    if ($matchingItem) {
        return array_merge($item, $matchingItem);
    }
    
    return $item;
});
```

and

```
    $res = $collection1->map(function ($item) use ($collection2) {
        $item = (array)$item;

        $matchingItem = $collection2->where('id', $item['id'])->first();

        if ($matchingItem) {
            return array_merge($item, $matchingItem);
        }

        $itemZ[] = (object)$item;
        $itemZZ = (object)$itemZ;
        $itemZZZ = collect($itemZ);

        return $itemZZZ;
    });
```

But mostly I get a collection with the `items` being an array where it should be an class and also the values arn't updated.
I did not think it would be this tricky, but I cant seem to get it to return the same format as the original. and the update fails aswell.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting this collections from? Maybe you can solve it by not having 2 collections in the first place, but I have no idea where are the comming from

Comment: @matiaslauriti 2 queries that return these 2 collections. Not the one needs to be updated with the other.

Comment: I am asking this because it is very weird that one collection has the other one 100%, I would say you tweak the 2 queries into one, and let the database handle what tou want to filter or map, it is going to be way more performant than PHP

Comment: What's wrong with `$collection1->merge($collection2)`?

Comment: I then get a collection with two `items` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array merge and [data_get](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-data-get)

here's a basic example

```
$array1 = collect([
    ['key1' => 0, 'key2' => 1],
    [],
    [],
    ['key1' => 6, 'key2' => 7],
]);

$array2 = collect([
    ['key1' => 11, 'key2' => 10],
    ['key1' => 2, 'key2' => 3],
    ['key1' => 4, 'key2' => 5],
    ['key1' => 12, 'key2' => 13],
    ['key1' => 14, 'key2' => 15],
]);
```

merging based on array1 collection items (array2 item values will overwrite array1 items);

```
return $array1->map( fn($item, $key) => array_merge($item, data_get($array2, $key) ?? [] ) );

//output
[
    { key1: 11, key2: 10 },
    { key1: 2, key2: 3 },
    { key1: 4, key2: 5 },
    { key1: 12, key2: 13 }
]
```

merging based on array2 collection items  (array1 item values  will overwrite array2 items);

```
return $array2->map( fn($item, $key) => array_merge($item, data_get($array1, $key) ?? [] ) );
//output
[
    { key1: 0, key2: 1 },
    { key1: 2, key2: 3 },
    { key1: 4, key2: 5 },
    { key1: 6, key2: 7 },
    { key1: 14, key2: 15 }
]
```

Also, post the actual result of the collection you are trying to merge,

you can get them by

```
return [
    'c1' => $collection1,
    'c2' => $collection2
];
```

or

```
dd( $collection1->toArray(), $collection2->toArray() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this with example

```
$collection1 = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bob'],
]);

$collection2 = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bob Smith'],
]);

$updatedCollection1 = $collection1->map(function ($item) use ($collection2) {
    $matchingItem = $collection2->where('id', $item['id'])->first();
    if ($matchingItem) {
        return array_merge($item, $matchingItem);
    }
    return $item;
});

// $updatedCollection1 now contains the following values:
// [
//     ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe'],
//     ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jane'],
//     ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bob Smith'],
// ]
```

This approach works with unique key (here id is unique)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 Collection, one could simply use `merge` of Collection to merge this 2 Collections together:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-merge

From the description

> "[...]If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given item's value will overwrite the value in the original collection[...]"

So, as far as I understand it, this is exactly what you want to get.

Comment: Not really. For some reason when I use merge I end up with two objects in the $items array.

Answer (score 0):

Because $matchingItem and $item are a class instance. To use array_merge, you need to convert them to array and to get object response, convert the result of array_merge to object

```
$updatedCollection = $collection1->map(function ($item) use ($collection2) {
    $matchingItem = $collection2->where('id', $item['id'])->first();
    
    if ($matchingItem) {
        return (object) array_merge((array) $item, (array) $matchingItem);
    }
    
    return $item;
});
```